# CSS selector to select first instance with nth-type-of(1) fail when markup changed

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This has me stumped...

[**SEE JSBIN HERE**](http://jsbin.com/uyimif/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
    .slide-nav:nth-of-type(1) { color:red } /* this should select the number 1 */
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="image">
    <span class="slide" data-order="4" rel="content-images/teta.jpg" ></span>
    <span class="slide" data-order="3" rel="content-images/champ.jpg" ></span>
    <span class="slide" data-order="2" rel="content-images/clouds.jpg" ></span>
    <img class="slide initial" data-order="1" src="content-images/air.jpg" />
    <span class="spinner"></span>

    <!--  
    delete this line to comment the two arrow links -->
    <a class="arrow next" href="javascript:void(0)">&rarr;</a>
    <a class="arrow prev" href="javascript:void(0)">&larr;</a>
    <!-- -->

    <a class="slide-nav on" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="1">1</a>
    <a class="slide-nav" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="2">2</a>
    <a class="slide-nav" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="3">3</a>
    <a class="slide-nav" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="4">4</a>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

### Question

Why does the `.slide-nav:nth-of-type(1) { color:red }` only work when the two additional links above the numbers are removed?

In the jsbin, delete the two arrows, or delete the commented line to comment that block and you'll see that the `.slide-nav:nth-of-type(1)` selector works magically.

For the life of me, it appears that it should just work regardless. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no filter by class in CSS because it does not have a :nth-of-class() selector. `:nth-of-type` filter has to be on a tag.

A workaround is to wrap your slide-nav links inside a span and filter for all `a`s inside in CSS.

```
<span class="numbers">
    <a class="slide-nav on" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="1">1</a>
    <a class="slide-nav" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="2">2</a>
    <a class="slide-nav" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="3">3</a>
    <a class="slide-nav" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="4">4</a>
</span>
```

And the CSS

```
span.numbers a:nth-of-type(1) { color:red; } /* this should select the number 1 */
```

For an example see http://jsfiddle.net/3J4K6/

Comment: @Moin Zaman, if the arrows are removed, then the `a` element with content “1” becomes the first child of its type (i.e., the first `a` element) inside the `div`. But when the arrows are there, the first of them (and not the element you want) matches the selector `:nth-of-type(1)`. And since it does not match `.slide-nav`, the combined selector `.slide-nav:nth-of-type(1)` is not matched by any element here.

Comment: In addition to what @Jukka K. Korpela has said, it's therefore a good idea to qualify `:nth-of-type()` with a type selector (the name used in the spec to mean "tag name", clarified in Selectors 4) rather than a class selector. To be fair, the name `:nth-of-type()` itself was a poor choice, as most authors don't associate "element type" with "element tag name".