# Select children of nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having real trouble understanding how to select the children of an nth-of-type selection.

I want the labels with the selection .formdiv:nth-of-type(1) to be shorter than the labels in all the other divs selected with .formdiv

This is easiest to explan via the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LSjLT/1/

I need the labels containing text1 and text2 to be less wide than the labels containing longer text.

What I find particularly odd is that the selector I have written works fine in jQuery (returns the right nodes), but doesn't seem to work in css:

```
.formdiv:nth-of-type(1) label{
    width: 60px;
}
```

My html is as follows:

```
<form id="settings">
    <div class="formdiv">
        <label for ="text1">text1:</label>
        <input id="text1"></input>
        </br>   

        <label for = "text2">text2:</label>
        <input id="text2"></input>
        </br>   

        </br>   
    </div>
    <div class="formdiv">
        <label for = "longer text 1">longer text 1:</label>
        <input id="longer text 1"></input>
        </br>   

        <label for = "longer text 2">longer text 2:</label>
        <input id="longer text 2"></input>
        </br>   

        </br>   
    </div>
    <div class="formdiv">
        <label for = "longer text 1">longer text 1:</label>
        <input id="longer text 1"></input>
        </br>   

        <label for = "longer text 2">longer text 2:</label>
        <input id="longer text 2"></input>
        </br>   

        </br>   
    </div>
</form>
```

and my current css:

```
#settings .formdiv label {
  font: 12px Arial;
  text-align: right;
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;

}

#settings input {
  display: inline-block;
}

.formdiv {
  display:inline-block;
}

/*This doesn't seem to work!*/
.formdiv:nth-of-type(1) label{
    width: 60px;
}
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Robin

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector to select first instance with nth-type-of(1) fail when markup changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767044/css-selector-to-select-first-instance-with-nth-type-of1-fail-when-markup-chang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `#settings .formdiv label{}` is overriding `.formdiv:nth-of-type(1) label{}` because it has an ID and because it's targeting the `width` property for every `<label>`

Prepend the `#settings` element on `.formdiv:nth-of-type(1) label` to increase its [specifcity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/):

```
#settings .formdiv:nth-of-type(1) label{
    width: 60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LSjLT/12/

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the clear explanation.  You wouldn't believe how long I just wasted fiddling with this before posting a question!

Answer (score 3):

Add a space between `.formdiv` and `:nth-of-type(1)`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/LSjLT/5/)

```
.formdiv :nth-of-type(1){
    color:red;
}
```

You were selecting the `nth-of-type` of `.formdiv`.

Adding the space selects `nth-of-type` of the children elements of `.formdiv`.

The same would also work with `.formdiv :first-of-type` [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/LSjLT/11/)

Note the space again.

Comment: Wouldn't that equate to `:first-child`? Wouldn't you actually want to target what tag you're after? Like `.formdiv label:nth-of-type(1) { color: red; }`?

Comment: @Stigma Yep! You're completely right, I misread the question. Nonetheless, 1+ for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
.formdiv:nth-of-type(1) label{
width: 60px !important;
}
```

Using id is not be good practice in css. Add this in your code, you can see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
.formdiv:first-of-type input {css}
```